# How to define a unicode ± operator in R

Tags: r

I want to define ± operator like this:

```
`±` <- function(a,b){
    return (c(a*b, a-b))
}
```

But the problem is I get this error on running `1 ± 2`

```
Error: unexpected input in "1 ±"
```

If I use a different characters it works.

```
`%+-%` <- function(a,b){
    return (c(a+b, a-b))
}
```

Running `1 %+-% 2` gives me `[1]  3 -1` which is correct.

Is it due to operator being an unicode character? But I can define and use unicode variables fine.

---

EDIT:

I found this:

> You can define your own binary operators. User-defined binary operators consist of a string of characters between two “%” characters.

In [Adler, Joseph (2010). R in a Nutshell. O’Reilly Media Inc](https://paulvanderlaken.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/r_in_a_nutshell.pdf)

So I guess `%` around the operator is a must.

Comment: Your second example works because you're using `%` symbols, not because it's a different character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing specific about the `±` operator, you can either do

```
`±` <- function(a,b){
    return (c(a*b, a-b))
}

`±`(1,2)
#[1]  2 -1
```

or using the `%` notation:

```
`%±%` <- function(a,b){
    return (c(a*b, a-b))
}

1 %±% 2
#[1]  2 -1
```

@Atreyagaurav points out in the comments that valid operator tokens (such as `+` or `-`) can be redefined. However this method does not allow *new* operators to be defined. The full list of such operators is given in
[The R language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html) section 10.3.6.

Section 10.3.4 indicates that *additional special operators* are defined as starting and ending with the `%` symbol.

Comment: It works when called like `\`±\`(1,2)` but it doesn;t when I call it like `1 ± 2`

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to define arbitrary characters as binary operators like that with any symbol, which is why the `%` notation was introduced

Comment: Interesting, when I searched how to define operators I saw the examples with `%..%` But none of them said anything about it being a must. So I thought it was a convention. Specially since `+` or `-` can be redefined with a function. It feels odd that `\`±\`(1,2) ` works but not `1±2`.

Comment: @Atreyagaurav R function names are supposed to start with letters or periods unless escaped.  The %op% conventions is for defining binary operators. Surely would would need to use `\`±\`` (with backticks which are problematic in comments on SO but escaping with backslash seems to work here) instead of a naked ± if you had first defined an S4 method for that symbol. Might be possible. You might need to assign it to the `Arith` group of operators. See `?Arith` and follow lots of the links to S4 related functions. Defining S4 methods is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66436990/group-generic-methods-for-ops-for-time-series